# Parts of the UI not showing in a release version

Tags: android, flutter

I have a flutter app that runs perfectly in debug mode on android emulator, physical device even the release version of the iOS is fine. but on the android release apk the issue appears. it doesn't show a grid view on the home page.
as in the screenshots below.
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUrDS.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Somehow when I build it again. it just worked. I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

It because you didn't observe the error shown during debug.

> Try to run it in debug mode again, check your debug console, there is a warning from the widget. perhaps the alignment of with and height...the log will tel you what is wrong.

Fix and you will be fine

Comment: I already tried that before and cleared all the warnings but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution for this issue is that you need to fix an error of this type :**

> ```
> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget Error in Flutter
> ```

[image]

It seems clean but flutter in **debug mode** doesn't pay strict attention to the tree order which is not the same case in the **release mode** and this cause a UI problem, technicaly :

> This error occurs when the Child widget has not matched the parent
> widget

To solve this error, your child widget must have the expected parent widget. Some of the widget and their parent widgets are:

[image]

Make sure to have the right parent for all the widgets using this Table, and you will be good to go!